# Launching Chrome Headless in Selenium WebDriver still results in a blank browser window

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, webdriver, headless

I'm trying to launch Chrome headless in WebDriver I am seeing that a blank browser window still pops up while the tests execute.

My code looks like this:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOpt = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOpt.AddArguments("--headless");
chromeOpt.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOpt);
```

The Chrome browser is Version 59.0.3071.115.
And I am utilizing the Selenium.WebDriver (.NET bindings for the Selenium WebDriver API NuGet package) version 3.4.0 in Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my problem by adding a reference to version 2.31.0 of the Chrome.WebDriver.ChromeDriver NuGet package to my project.

Comment: There's no NuGet package of that name. As far as I can tell there's no official package for the Chrome WebDriver - only several unofficial ones. E.g. `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` which is actually published by `jsakamoto` despite the name implying it's an official Selenium package. Also `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver`, by `jbaranda`. And numerous less popular ones. Which did you use? I tried `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` 2.31.0 but it still seems to open a Chrome window even with those arguments.

Comment: I initially had referenced the Selenium.WebDriver (by Selenium Committers) version 3.4.  That reference is still in place.  I then added on the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 2.31.0 by jsakamoto.  With this setup Chrome is running headless without any blank window showing.